# How is the subtraction of a uniform (0, k) and its entire part distributed?

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

Let X be a random variable distributed as $U[0, K]$ for an integer K. Find the density function of $Y = f (x) = x- [x]$, where [x] denotes the integer part of the real number x.

I think that [X] represents a discrete uniform but this by definition would be with values at x = 1,2, ... k, and its density would be 1/k which is the same as that of the continuous uniform.

Now, I understand that the distribution [X] is dependent on X, then I could not assume independence to use some kind of transformation because I do not know the joint.

I appreciate if you can give me some other way that I have not considered, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, set $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ to be the fractional part of $x$. Check that $\{x\} \in [0,1)$. Hence, $f_X(x)$ is defined for $x\in [0,1)$. Let's compute the CDF. Fix a $c\in[0,1)$, and study $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}\leq c)$. Observe that,
$$
\{\{x\} \leq c\}=\bigcup_{k=0}^{K-1}\{x\in [k,k+c)\},
$$
hence $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}\leq c)=K\cdot \frac{c}{K}=c$. Hence, it turns out that, $\{x\}$ is uniform on $[0,1)$ (and also, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is uniform on $\{0,\dots,K-1\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood.